# Foundation menu - mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, zurb-foundation

I have the problem that when I make 2 lines in my menu , so it does not show all the menu items . What can I do about this ? For the calculates a height and the height are calculated in a menu item only takes up one line. What do I do?

http://kvejborg.dk/

Comment: If I correctly understand your issue, after inspecting the menu elements, your menu is overflowing and can not be scrolled. I found a tag `.submenu.submenu.submenu.submenu` in your stylesheet which contains a background color (don't understand why it has the same class 4 times though), just add a `overflow: auto;` to it.

Comment: On mobile device? 
Its not the normal navbar. We need to get on a mobile view.